# How do I open a new tab in chrome window through a button in the popup of my web extension?

Tags: javascript, flask

I am working on a chrome extension and I have added a button in the popup of this extension that should send a request to the flask server which renders the feedback form. [image: Extension Popup]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <form id="form" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/feedback">
  <div class="col gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center">
    <h3 class="mb-1">Report Dark Patterns</h3>
    <p class="fw-light lh-sm">Help us grow by reporting any suspected dark patterns that we missed</p>
    
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>
  <script>
      const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
      submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      window.open("http://127.0.0.1:5000/feedback", "_blank");
});

  </script>
</body>
```

```
@app.route("/feedback")
def show_form():
    return render_template("form.html")
```

Everything is working if I open the popup.html separately and then click the button. But, through the extension popup, it's not happening.!!

I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of that. Just use

```
window.location.href = '/feedback';
```

Comment: Note if use 127.0.0.1 will always redirect to localhost. Maybe you should use only '/feedback' to redirects current_domain/feedback

Comment: agreed. just edited.